# Is there a kubernetes cronjob kind which allows multiple schedules for a single container image?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

If one has an image with a number of different executables, is it possible to have multiple cron entries with different commands that run at different times in the same kubernetes deployment.

e.g. For some single container image named "jolly-roger", I want to schedule the following crontab, without having to manage 4 separate kubernetes applications in different repositories.

```
*/30 * * * * /pirate-bin/rehoist-the-flag
0 7,19 * * * /pirate-bin/feed-the-sharks
45 20 * * * /pirate-bin/count-the-gold
0 12 * * 1,5 /pirate-bin/make-landlubbers-walk-the-plank
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can:

- create a single cronjob resource with exactly one crontab time (like `*/30 * * * *`) and several containers to run
- create several cronjob resources using the same container images but different `command` and `args` for each job

You can not:

- create one cron job resource with several crontab times
- consequently not using multiple containers with multiple crontab times

So in short, you can place all your binaries in a single container, but cannot solve your problem by defining one resource. The way to go is to use the same image in a distinct cronjob resource per crontab line of your example

Answer (score 1):

Using helm, I was able to do it by defining my cronjob values in the `values.yaml`:

```
cronJobs:
  - name: daily
    schedule: "0 13 * * 1-5"
  - name: weekly
    schedule: "@weekly"
  - name: monthly
    schedule: "@monthly*"
```

And then in my template, I can use `range` to iterate over it and create as many CronJob as I want:

```
{{- range .Values.cronJobs }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-{{ .name }}-job
  labels:
    app: {{ template "test.name" $ }}
    chart: {{ template "test.chart" $ }}
    release: {{ $.Release.Name }}
    component: test
spec:
  schedule: {{ .schedule | quote }}

[...]

---
{{- end }}
```

> Note that you need to use `$` instead of `.` to access root scope (like the `Release.Name` for example). This is because the scope is changed by the `range` block (cf. [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/))